# MySQL wont start in MAMP on mac running El Capitan 10.11.6

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mamp

I downloaded mamp two weeks ago, and have been working on my new wordpress site offline.  my battery died so I restarted my computer and when I launched mamp, the apache light turned green, but mysql didn't start.  I tried killing the mysql process from the activity monitor and terminal.  I'm not sure what to do.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'v had lots of issues with it....The thing that helped me out was uninstalling mamp and reinstalling it again.To be honest i have to do it often :D

Comment: if i uninstall mamp and reinstall, do i lose my offline wordpress site??

Comment: Make a copy of the htdocs

Comment: Also export your database

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: Do you have some errors in the log? Normally you should get one something.

Comment: pretend I'm an idiot.  I'm brand new to this.  I just made a backup of the main mamp folder in applications.  should I delete mamp and reinstall.  I'm not new to programming, but new to mamp and wordpress

Comment: I am almost done with my website which I've been working on locally